# Apply two materials for two segment at single mesh

Tags: blender, unreal-engine4

i have one mesh from 100 pieces (a gun) and materials are from Blender separated into two segments.. main material and steel material. I generated all maps (normal, roughness etc.) from Substance painter for each segment. When I exported mesh from Blender I have milion of pieces and not single mesh. Its ok, I can join them, but how can I apply two materials to joined mesh please in UE? Do I need to export fbx for each segment (after join from blender) and then put them together in UE or there is different and native was to do this please?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, i exported as .obj and not as .fbx and it works good. Just assign two materials and finish